# Containing resources used by automatic apt-config

Tags: debian, cpu-usage, apt

I am running Debian Linux 9 (Stretch) with a 4.9 kernel, and I notice periodically the system launches an `apt-config` process with user `_apt` that uses 100% CPU and consumes enough resources that I can't mount or unmount volumes, much less use desktop functions (in my case KDE Plasma).

I thought this might be due to the installation of the unattended-upgrades package that is now installed by default as described on the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades), but following the procedure to disable with the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades` did not help.

I see no similar resource consumption issues when I open a console and use `aptitude` or `dselect`, or if I use `Discover`, even though these programs will also open an `apt-config` process with user `_apt` that uses 100% CPU.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: +1 exactly same environment and problem. I've inspected /var/log/apt/ but found nothing related. I wonder where is the place to find the logs of apt-config, and preferably also the procedure envoking apt-config...

Comment: Yeah.  I never figured out how this was precisely getting invoked and what makes it different than using `aptitude` or `dselect`.  I simply removed `unattended-upgrades` and went back to manual updating.  If that works for you, maybe we should put it up as an answer although it doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: +1 same issue on KDE, debian stretch, backports kernel. I have two machines with unattended-upgrades, but this issue only affects one of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [debian bug #881787](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=881787). Packagekit is checking for updates every 5-10 minutes on a Stretch KDE system. You can see this in `systemctl status packagekit`.

The packagekit logs also show how long the checks take. On my system they took over 500 seconds and so were running basically constantly.

The `apper` package may be responsible.

I had this package installed. I uninstalled it and have now successfully gone a whole 30 minutes without any new entries appearing in the packagekit logs. So that solved it for me!

Comment: Thanks for finding this!  I found the same lines in my syslog, and removing apper seems to clear it up.

Comment: I had the problem recur four days later, and now have removed all of `PackageKit` and `plasma-discover`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. I don't know exactly what happened, but I think executing `pkcon refresh` fixed it. (`pkcon` is part of [`packagekit-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/packagekit-tools).) Execution took quite some time, maybe 3 minutes. The progress was stuck at `Downloading packages` for most of the time — first at 98% and some time later at 99%, like this:

```
Refreshing cache              [=========================]
Waiting in queue              [=========================]
Loading cache                 [=========================]
Refreshing software list      [=========================]
Downloading packages          [======================== ] (98%)
```

99%:

```
Downloading packages          [======================== ] (99%)
```

The final output was as follows:

```
Refreshing cache              [=========================]
Waiting in queue              [=========================]
Loading cache                 [=========================]
Refreshing software list      [=========================]
Downloading packages          [=========================]
Running                       [=========================]
Finished                      [=========================]
 Enabled                              http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
 ...
 ...
 ...
```

Now executing `pkcon refresh` and `pkcon refresh force` takes only 1 or 2 seconds:

```
Refreshing cache              [=========================]
Loading cache                 [=========================]
Downloading packages          [=========================]
Finished                      [=========================]
 Enabled                              http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
 ...
```